# Implement "Search" functionality on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am trying to search on the recyclerview items. For this I've implemented `Filterable`. Problem is - instaed of matched items, I am getting the whole list of items. Here is the constructor of the Adapter class :

```
public RecyclerAdapter (ArrayList<List<ResponseModel>> items) {
    this.items = items; // original items
    this.tempItems = items; // for searching purpose
}
```

Here is the overrided method :

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                String charString = constraint.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    items = tempItems;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<List<ResponseModel>> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (List<ResponseModel> responseModel : tempItems) {
                        for (int i =0; i < tempItems.size() ; i++) {
                            if (responseModel.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)){
                                filteredList.add(responseModel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    items = filteredList;

                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = items;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                items = (ArrayList<List<ResponseModel>>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }
```

Here is onCreate optionsMenu inside a Fragment class :

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView sv = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic `Filterable` adapter as a base class and override its `matches()` method

Comment: Seems complex. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: complex? in implementing just two simple methods (`onBindHolder()` and `matches()`)? now try to compare it to what you already wrote...

Comment: I'm not clear about it. Ok, what do mean by using it as base class?

Comment: `class Adapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<YourDataPOJO, Adapter.VH> { ...`

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely try this & will let you know.

Comment: Anyway,  I would be pleased if you check my existing code. I think the bug is inside the "for" loop.

Comment: then refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85#file-matchablervarrayadapte-pure-recyclerview-style-no-implicit-textview-mapping-L304) `Filter` implementation and see how it works

Comment: Sorry. Unable. Can you show me an example by using that adapter?

Comment: what unable? what does not work? only filtering?
 what methods did you override and how?

Comment: onBindHolder(), onCreateViewHolder() and matches(). kept the code of my onBindViewHolder()'s code inside onBindHolder(). Unable to understand. It'll be better if you give an example by using that adapter.

Comment: `onCreateHolder` is abstract and you should implement that method, not `onCreateViewHolder`, the rest is OK so what does not work? just filtering?

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions.** A bunch of chatter has been removed. If you want to add additional information, edit the question. If you want to share a working solution, add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below in you `publishResultsMethod`

```
 @Override
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll((ArrayList<List<ResponseModel>>) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: This time, though search query matches, nothing is being shown.